# Spark application uses only 1 executor after run flatMap function

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have an application that calculates the level of product interest using apache-spark. I use `groupBy` to group products by category, then use `flatMap` to combine data to save into mongodb. However, when it comes to the code to save data, only one executor will run, resulting in a timeout of the program's large data.
I then used the `repartition` function to optimize the program, but when running to this section, only one executor ran, resulting in the `org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException` due to timeout.
How to overcome this situation? My config when submit:

```
    spark.executor.memory 15G
    spark.executor.instances 8
    spark.executor.cores 10
    spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -Xms3600m
    spark.debug.maxToStringFields=10000
    spark.executor.heartbeatInterval 1900000s
    spark.network.timeout 2000000s
    spark.rpc.askTimeout 2100000s
    spark.core.connection.ack.wait.timeout 1900000s
    spark.shuffle.memoryFraction 0
    spark.memory.offHeap.enabled true
    spark.memory.offHeap.size = 12G
```

My source code:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .master("spark://" + sparkMaster + ":7077")
                //.master("local")
                .appName("Products")
                .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://" + mongoDBServer + "/product-repository.detail")
                .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://" + mongoDBServer + "/product-repository.mark")
                .config("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster")
                .getOrCreate();

        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

        JavaMongoRDD<Document> rdd = MongoSpark.load(jsc);
        JavaRDD<ProductDetail> detailRDD = rdd.filter(new Function<Document, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(Document doc) throws Exception {
                long currentId = doc.getLong("ProductVersion");
                for (long id : listProductVersion)
                    if (id == currentId) return true;
                return false;
            }
        }).map(new Function<Document, ProductDetail>() {
            @Override
            public ProductDetail call(Document doc) throws Exception {
                CategoryDetail cate = categoryDetails.stream()
                        .filter(x -> x.CategoryUrl.equals(doc.getString("CategoryUrl")))
                        .findAny()
                        .orElse(new CategoryDetail());

                String cateName = cate.CategoryName;
                int cateId = cate.CategoryId;

                //LOGGER.info("Convert to product detail, Id: " + doc.getObjectId("_id"));
                return new ProductDetail(
                        doc.getLong("ProductVersion"),
                        doc.getObjectId("_id"),
                        doc.getString("CategoryUrl"),
                        ConvertStringToInteger(doc.get("AggregateRating", Document.class)),
                        GetPrice(doc, "ListPrice"),
                        GetPrice(doc, "Price"),
                        GetDiscountPercent(doc),
                        GetProductUrl(doc),
                        GetUrl(doc),
                        cateName,
                        cateId
                );
            }
        });

        JavaPairRDD<Integer, Iterable<ProductDetail>> groupData = detailRDD.groupBy(new Function<ProductDetail, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call(ProductDetail p) throws Exception {
                return p.CategoryId;
            }
        });

        // calculate max rating count
        JavaPairRDD<Integer, Iterable<Document>> results = groupData.mapValues(new Function<Iterable<ProductDetail>, Iterable<Document>>() {
            @Override
            public Iterable<Document> call(Iterable<ProductDetail> productDetails) throws Exception {

                int minR = 9999, maxR = 0;
                int sum = 0, count = 0;

                for (ProductDetail p : productDetails) {
                    if (p.MarkRating > maxR) maxR = p.MarkRating;
                    if (p.MarkRating < minR) minR = p.MarkRating;
                    sum += p.MarkRating;
                    count++;
                }

                if (count > 0) {
                    double avg = (double) sum / count;
                    for (ProductDetail p : productDetails) {
                        p.MaxMarkCategory = maxR;
                        p.MinMarkCategory = minR;
                        p.AvgMarkCategory = avg;
                    }
                }

                List<Document> result = new ArrayList<>();
                for (ProductDetail p : productDetails) {
                    Document doc = new Document();
                    doc.append("Id", p.Id);
                    doc.append("CategoryUrl", p.CategoryUrl);
                    doc.append("Category", p.Category);
                    doc.append("DetailUrl", p.DetailUrl);
                    doc.append("Url", p.Url);
                    doc.append("ListPrice", p.ListPrice);
                    doc.append("Price", p.Price);
                    doc.append("DiscountPercent", p.DiscountPercent);
                    doc.append("MarkRating", GetMarkRating(p.MarkRating, p.MaxMarkCategory));
                    doc.append("MinMarkCategory", p.MinMarkCategory);
                    doc.append("MaxMarkCategory", p.MaxMarkCategory);
                    doc.append("AvgMarkCategory", p.AvgMarkCategory);
                    doc.append("ProductVersion", p.ProductVersion);
                    doc.append("MarkVersion", markVersion);
                    doc.append("TimeStamp", timeStamp);

                    result.add(doc);
                }
                return result;
            }
        });


        JavaRDD<Document> flatMapResult = results.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<Integer, Iterable<Document>>, Document>() {
            @Override
            public Iterator<Document> call(Tuple2<Integer, Iterable<Document>> integerIterableTuple2) throws Exception {
                return integerIterableTuple2._2.iterator();
            }
        }).repartition(1000);

        Map<String, String> writeOverrides = new HashMap<String, String>();
        writeOverrides.put("collection", "mark");
        writeOverrides.put("writeConcern.w", "majority");
        WriteConfig writeConfig = WriteConfig.create(jsc).withOptions(writeOverrides);

        MongoSpark.save(flatMapResult, writeConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use repartition before flatMap.

Spark will make use one core per partition.

You can verify this behavior in Spark UI.

Comment: I think that after running flatMap, there is only 1 partition so I uses repartition function, does using the flatMap function before it work?